# Windows Forms C# JSON Data doesn't show after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I'm trying to pull data from an API and show the data inside `DataGridView` control, but after deserializing the data, it shows:

[image: this instead].

Code for a `Button1` Click event:

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var postData = new PostData
                {
                    id=5,
                    title = "yeni",
                    description = "yenidesc",
                    type_name="yenitype"
                };

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("-i_know_that_my_uri_should_be_here-");

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = client.PostAsync("products",content).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var postResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(responseContent); //JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PostResponse>(responseContent);
                    MessageBox.Show("help: "+ postResponse);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = postResponse;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hata: " + response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
```

And this is my `PostData` class:

```
public class PostData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string type_name { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is my `PostResponse` class:

```cs
 public class PostResponse
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string type_name { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is my JSON file:

```json
{"message":"product data has been taken successfully","products":[{"id":116,"title":"GASA","description":"fdsafsd","situation":1,"type_name":"Kasa","type_id":1,"features":[{"products_type_feature_id":56,"feature_name":"Marka","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"efwef"},{"products_type_feature_id":57,"feature_name":"Model","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"wefw"},{"products_type_feature_id":58,"feature_name":"Kasa Tipi","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":59,"feature_name":"Kasa Boyutu","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"fwef"},{"products_type_feature_id":60,"feature_name":"Renk","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"fewe"},{"products_type_feature_id":61,"feature_name":"Malzeme","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":62,"feature_name":"Soğutma Sistemi","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"wefw"},{"products_type_feature_id":63,"feature_name":"Ön Panel Bağlantı Noktaları","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"efwef"},{"products_type_feature_id":64,"feature_name":"Ağırlık","feature_unit_name":"kg","feature":"fwefwef"},{"products_type_feature_id":65,"feature_name":"İşlemci Modeli","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":66,"feature_name":"Anakart Modeli","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":67,"feature_name":"Bellek Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":68,"feature_name":"HDD Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":69,"feature_name":"SSD Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":70,"feature_name":"Ekran Kartı Modeli","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":71,"feature_name":"Ekran Kartı Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":72,"feature_name":"İşletim Sistemi","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":73,"feature_name":"Güç Kaynağı Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"Watt","feature":""}]},{"id":115,"title":"nııgaaa","description":"gfdgfd","situation":1,"type_name":"Laptop","type_id":2,"features":[{"products_type_feature_id":43,"feature_name":"Marka","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":44,"feature_name":"Model","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":45,"feature_name":"Ekran Boyutu","feature_unit_name":"inç","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":46,"feature_name":"İşlemci Modeli","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":47,"feature_name":"Bellek Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":48,"feature_name":"HDD Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":49,"feature_name":"SSD Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":50,"feature_name":"Ekran Kartı Modeli","feature_unit_name":"","feature":"a"},{"products_type_feature_id":51,"feature_name":"Ekran Kartı Kapasitesi","feature_unit_name":"GB","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":52,"feature_name":"İşletim Sistemi","feature_unit_name":"","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":53,"feature_name":"Batarya Ömrü","feature_unit_name":"saat","feature":""},{"products_type_feature_id":54,"feature_name":"Ağırlık","feature_unit_name":"kg","feature":""}]}]}
```

By the way, this is my first post on StackOverflow. I deeply apologise if I've made any mistakes.

I've tried using `System.Text.Json`, but it was still the same result.
I was expecting it to work fine and list in `DataGridView`, but no, it didn't.

Comment: Well, yeah, `"help: "+ postResponse` will call the `.ToString()` of `PostResponse` which since you haven't overridden, will just give you the class full name. Either create an override or pick what specific fields you want to show.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Comment: Also, you might want to try https://json2csharp.com/ to automate building the proper class.  In your example, json2csharp should give you an array somewhere, which you then use a the source for your datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`DataGridView.DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks), you should provide values with these types:

- The `IList` interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
- The `IListSource` interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
- The `IBindingList` interface, such as the BindingList class.
- The `IBindingListView` interface, such as the BindingSource class.

While the JSON response you try to deserialize does not match the `PostResponse` structure. The `PostResponse` structure should be as:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PostResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<ProductData> Products { get; set; }
    
}

public class ProductData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type_name")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And you should provide the `postResponse.products` to `dataGridView1.DataSource`.

```cs
var postResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(responseContent);
dataGridView1.DataSource = postResponse.Products;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Side note:

1. Since your method is `async`, you should use the `await` instead of `/* Task */.Result` to avoid the deadlock.

```cs
var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

to:

```cs
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

2. Declare the property name with Pascal case instead of camel case.

Comment: Thank you so much.

It's working now and i am able to list the api data in datagridview.

Much appreciated.